# Connection between differential form of a manifold and Sheaf of relative differential of a map of schemes.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, soft-question, sheaf-theory, smooth-manifolds

I was wondering whether there is a connection between the differential form of a manifold and Sheaf of Relative differential of a Scheme map.

Definitions: Differential form on a manifold M is a map $\omega: M \rightarrow \sqcup _{p\in M}T_p^{*}(M)$ such that $\omega(p)\in T_p^{*}(M)$

Sheaf of differentials relative to a map $f:X\rightarrow Y$: There exists a unique quasi-coherent sheaf $\Omega_{X/Y}$ on X such that for any affine open subset $V$ of $Y$, any affine open subset $U$ of $f^{-1}(V)$, we have

$\Omega_{X/Y}|_{U}\cong(\Omega_{\mathcal O_{X}(U)/ {\mathcal O_{Y}}(V)})^{\sim}$

Comment: What do you mean by connection? The (relative) cotangent sheaf is the algebro-geometric analogue of the tangent bundle. For example, if you believe that $\mathfrak{m}_x/\mathfrak{m}_x^2$ is the 'cotangent space' of $X$ at $x$, and if $X\to S$ is finite type, with $k(x)/k(s)$ separable, then $\mathfrak{m}_x/\mathfrak{m}_x^2$ is isomorphic to the fiber of $\Omega^1_{X/S}$ at $x$. I can give you other geometric reasons why $\Omega^1$ is like a 'relative cotangent bundle', but I'm not sure what you mean. Are you wondering if you can literally phrase $T_M^\ast$ as some sheaf like this? (you can).

Comment: You need some more conditions on the map $\omega$ to say it is a differential form.

Comment: @Cantlog Do you mean the map should be smooth map of manifolds?

Comment: Something like that. But of course, as you wrote, the target space of $\omega$ has not an obivous structure of manifold.

Comment: The target space the tangent bundle has an obvious structure of manifold. In fact it will be a vector bundle over M. Also in literature when w is smooth we call it a smooth differential, otherwise we call it just a differential. (Smooth in the sense of map between two manifolds)